# Perron-Frobenius eigenvector with rational entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples, rational-numbers

I have the following question which I think should be simple to show but I have not succeeded so far in. I have a primitive matrix $A\in \big(\mathbb{N}_0\big) _{n\times n}$, with $\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,...\}$.
I know by the Perron-Frobenius theory that $A$ has a simple leading eigenvalue $\lambda$, with a corresponding eigenvector $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$ such that $\sum v_j=1$ and $v_j>0$ for all $j$. **If I assume that $\lambda\in \mathbb{Q}$, does this imply that $v_1,...,v_n\in \mathbb{Q}$ ?**

I've numerically computed this for some examples, but I was wondering whether this has to be the case or is there possibly a counter-example?

**Later edit:**
I also know that this does not work when I assume that the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector $\lambda$, is not rational. For example, for $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, the Perron-Frobenius eigenvetor is $\lambda = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Its normalized Perron-Frobenius eigenvector is $(\frac{1}{\lambda},\frac{1}{\lambda^2})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For any singular matrix with entries in a field $\mathbb F$, the standard row reduction methods to find vectors in the null space produce a vector with entries in $\mathbb F$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean this argument should work when the eigenvalue is not rational as well? Because I know the entries of the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector with norm $1$ of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ are not rational.

Comment: If a square matrix $A$ with entries in the field $\mathbb F$ has an eigenvector $v$ with entries in $\mathbb F$, then the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ must be in $\mathbb F$.  This is obvious from the eigenvalue equation $Av = \lambda v$.  So no, if $A$ has rational entries, an eigenvector for an irrational eigenvalue can't have rational entries.  The row reduction argument doesn't work because to find the eigenvector you do row reduction on $A - \lambda I$, not on $A$.

Comment: I thought this might be the issue after I wrote the comment, but thanks for verifying it.  Thanks again.